# HTTPURL connection in java 6/7

Tags: java, ssl, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I have a java code with HTTPURL connection it keep saying the error as below and it states error in 47th line.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target|

It also shows error in line   47:       OutputStream output = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

couldn't trace url responsecode, thou url is active to access.

here is the stack trace and javacode

https://gist.github.com/theakathir/c9138e3ea7470b698ec06a7db7dcdeab

Appreciate if someone could assist on this to resolve. Thanks

Comment: Please post the code on this site insted of just linking to an external source.

Comment: Hi... its extended page codes. and stack trace.... thats why i wrapped into a link... if you couldnt access the link please let me know i can try posting the whole code here

Comment: FYI there is no HTTP(S) response code (and no HTTP(S) response at all) when the SSL/TLS handshake fails (for any reason, not just certificate/PKIX validation)

Comment: I did some changes to import cert, now i see the error as  httpURLConnection string: 404
 java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input.|  thought url is reachable

Answer (score 2):

The server's domain certificate is usually signed by an intermediate certificate authority which in turn is signed by the root certificate authority. All common clients (browsers- chrome, mozilla, internet-explorer, safari, opera and the java-vm) have their own trust-store with the certificate authority already bundled during installation.

The exceptions means that you are pointing to a server whose server certificate has not been signed by a certificate authority trusted by the jvm.

In such cases you usually build your own trust-manager instead of modifying the jvm's default truststore (located at `$JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts`).

Code snippet would look something like this :

```
package com.example.so.tls;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;


/**
 * <p> https://stackoverflow.com/q/44607949/2862341 </p>
 * @author ravindra
 */
public class TestCustomTruststore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pathToTruststore = "/path/to/customTruststore.jks"; // truststore has the server certificate loaded
        try {
            File file = new File(pathToTruststore);
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), null);
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            String urlStr = "https://example.com";
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

            httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

PS: You'd need to use `$JAVA_HOME\bin\keytool` utility to create the keystore and load the certificate.

Comment: Hi... How i need to add the keystore and load certificate.... Appreciate if could sshare the details on steps how to do...Thanksss!

Comment: Hi I tried leveraging above piece of code... but setSSLSocketFactory is showing error as its undefined for HTTPURLConnection.... Can  you please advise whats wrong.thanks

Comment: You need to first obtain the certificate - ideally contact whoever is managing the server endpoint and ask for the certificate over a proven channel (you will need to trust the certificate after all). You can also simply access the endpoint in a browser and extract the certificate and confirm the thumbprint of the certificate with some contact-person on the server end. With regard to how to load the certificate into the keystore, you need to create a keystore first (that is what the keytool utility is for). Then you import the certificate into the keystore (the two steps can be combined).

Comment: Try : `keytool -importcert -file<cert_file> -keystore <name_of_truststore> -alias <my_server_cert_domain>
`. Also you need to cast the object to `HttpsURLConnection` and not `HttpURLConnection` notice the 's' after 'Http'.

Comment: Hi I have the certificate downloaded, but how do i know the name of truststore and domain ,... I couldnt find them in the details.... can you please brief what has to be taken care once the cert is downloaded. thanks

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, you need to import the certificate into the truststore. So you basically provide the truststore name when you create it! The domain is the same as the server you are trying to connect to  ( - the alias name).

Comment: Hi... Thanks  for your response... I did added SSL certificate code and imported the same , it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the certificate to the keystore file of the used JVM located at %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts.

First you can check if your certificate is already in the keystore by running the following command: keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" (you don't need to provide a password)

If your certificate is missing you can get it by downloading it with your browser and add it to the keystore with the following command:

keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias  -file    -keystore  -storepass

Afer import you can run the first command again to check if your certificate was added.

Comment: Hi... Thanks...can you please share the appropriate link to get the keystore downloaded, where the installation has to be stored and run the command to import?

Comment: The last 4 of those `-import` options require arguments. For java7 up another way to get the cert in importable form is with `keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$port] -rfc`

Comment: I did some changes to import cert, now i see the error as  httpURLConnection string: 404
 java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input.|  thought url is reachable .....any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A middle alternative is to use your own truststore file (not `JRE/lib/security/cacerts` or even `jssecacerts` which is an official alternative) but instead of writing code to load this file and use it in an `SSLSocketFactory` you can have the default factory use your file by setting system properties `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` . In many cases these can be set on the commandline to run your java program without any code change at all.

Note that nearly all SSL/TLS certificates on the Internet today are not issued directly by a root CA (which is in the various browser, client, and JVM truststores) but using an intermediate CA cert also called a 'chain' cert because it is used to chain from the server/leaf cert to the root. Occasionally there are two chain certs, and in principle can be even more. **Validation error might be caused not by your JVM lacking the root, but by the server failing to send the chain cert(s)**; you might not notice this error when accessing with a browser because browsers sometimes use other means of fetching the chain cert(s). In this case either examine the cert chain manually -- for java7 up you can use `keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$port]` and/or if you have openssl use `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -showcerts` and then use `openssl x509` on *each PEM block* in that output -- or use an automatic tester like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/